# Service Broker and WCF interoperability

Tags: sql-server, wcf, service, interop, service-broker

Does SQL Server Service Broker have an ability to communicate with a WCF service? I wanna create a Service Broker service which will send some xml message to WCF service for processing. Of course SQL Server instance and WCF service are deployed on different machines. Is it possible to somehow configure SB service to achieve such goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. SSB can only communicate with another SSB instance. There is a [WCF SSB channel](http://ssbwcf.codeplex.com/) but that is using SSB as a transport channel to a WCF service, the WCF service requires a local SQL Server for this channel to work (it can be SQL Express instance).