# Service Broker / External Application Activation and Visual Studio Debugging

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I just got moved to a code-base that uses a lot of Service Broker functionality.

My EAService.config is setup as below

```
<ApplicationService name="NotificationTest" enabled="true">
  <OnNotification>
    <ServerName>MyServer\MyInstance</ServerName>
    <DatabaseName>MyDatabase</DatabaseName>
    <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
    <QueueName>MyQueueName</QueueName>
  </OnNotification>
  <LaunchInfo>
    <ImagePath>C:\SomeFolder\SomeConsoleApp.exe</ImagePath>
    <CmdLineArgs>myCommandLineArg1</CmdLineArgs>
    <WorkDir>C:\SomeFolder\</WorkDir>
  </LaunchInfo>
  <Concurrency min="1" max="1" />
</ApplicationService>
```

My issue comes when I try to debug the above code.

Since the Service Broker External Activator (C:\Program Files\Service Broker\External Activator\Bin\ssbeas.exe) is instantiating the code....this is not something (to my best knowledge) that I can run in "Debug Mode" to wait for the call to come in and have a breakpoint set.

For example, with a WEBAPI project, I can do the traditional Start/Debug, and put a breakpoint on the ApiController/Method, and when a request comes in, it will break on the breakpoint, and I can pick up the debugging from there.

With Service Broker, it is instantiating some .exe....and the .exe may open and close so quickly, and I cannot "search and find" to attach a debugger to it.

I also thought, "Maybe I'll have Service Broker send messages to a WCF service", but that looks like it is not possible or very cumbersome to implement, based on what I read at this SOF post:

[Service Broker and WCF interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948407/service-broker-and-wcf-interoperability)

Is there anyway for me to do the above setup in EAService.config AND get the debugger to break as seen in the image below?

Or has anyone figured out a non hacky way to debug the C# code that is "activated" by Service Broker?

[image: Simple Console App]

Comment: In cases like this, I've always just gone "old school", I instrument the code with a lot of "trace" statements that write to the log.  It's hard-core and slow, but it works.  Takes a ton of patience and persistence though.

Comment: Old School.   That's what I'm fearing.  javascript:alert("stinkFactorValue=" + stinkFactor);

Comment: It's a good technique to become proficient in because it is pretty much the only one that works in virtually all conditions and environments.

Comment: @RBarryYoung https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

A. Modify the EAConfig to launch the program under debugger:

```
  <ImagePath>C:\PathToDebugger\YourDebuggerOfChoice.exe</ImagePath>
  <CmdLineArgs>C:\SomeFolder\SomeConsoleApp.exe myCommandLineArg1</CmdLineArgs>
```

B. Use [GFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549609(v=vs.85).aspx) image execution options to add a debugger to your app
C. Launch debugger from the app itself with [`Debugger.Launch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx)
D. Disable EA and run the application directly from VS (F5), for debugging purposes, then enable EA back.

Comment: I built a fair number of complex SSBEA scenarios. Definitely D, better still, wrap all "worker code" in a separate assembly, keep the activated console app (the exe) as slim as possible, also handling [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried "B" yesterday.....it would attach the debugger, but wouldn't "break" anywhere.  A is a brand new thought, so thanks for that.  And one idea I tried was a combination of A and C.  Edit the CmdLineArgs to include something like "DEBUGME", and then do this in the Main method.              int index = Array.FindIndex(args, x => x.Equals("DEBUGME", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (index > -1)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            }          Its a hack, but it works.

Comment: @granadaCoder option B depends on the debugger used. I'm not familiar with the VS debugging  command line, I'm a fan of [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306(v=vs.85).aspx) and there I would use  `-g` or not to 'initially break'. But I reckon that C# debugging in WinDbg is not exactly a 'pleasure'...

Comment: Also, a warning: while debugging you will very likely get your queue monitor into the 'notified' state. See http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/

Comment: @StefanAnghel interesting. If you ever have SSB questions, don't hesitate to contact me, I'm based in Bucharest nowadays.

Comment: vsjitdebugger.exe is the VS debugger.  I did try "C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\windbg.exe" as well.  Here is a good reference for these : http://bugslasher.net/2011/03/26/how-to-debug-a-process-as-soon-as-it-starts-with-windbg-or-visual-studio-2010/  His last note (about vsjitdebugger.exe) says "But remember that this way has a major drawback: Visual Studio will NOT start with the process in break mode: it will continue the execution, and the moment when you want to stop may be gone already…"  I think that is what I hit.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Yeah given your name I figured you're based somewhere over there. I'm based in northern Italy though.. Also you helped me a lot here on SO earlier on in figuring out SB. It appears there's at least two of us subscribed to the "service-broker" tag :D

Comment: Dang, and I've been doing it the hard way all these years. :-) Though, to be honest, I have used (D), I just couldn't remember (now) if EA apps were one of the contexts where that trick worked ...

Comment: @StefanAnghel I happened to do that as well and it's worked well for me. For me it was a lucky guess since I instantiate "any" class with my interface from the wrapper. I can also create unit tests for my worker assemblies and the outer broker wrapper was begun from a well-worn working example.  I did modify the wrapper to include a lot more tracing and error handling though.

Comment: @DavidStorfer sounds really well done, would love to see another source of a real-world trialed ssbea wrapper. 

Do share it if possibile, I'm sure it would help many people.


Sadly there isn't much out there, for some strange reason devs see SB as inferior to other open source queue managers, or just plain view it as too niche..

Comment: @StefanAnghel  - if you have the SQL 2008 Pro Service Broker book, in Chapter 10 there is a Batch Frameworks project.  I adapted that to run in SSBEA instead of being triggered as a C# stored proc.  Running as an SP was limiting because you can't use a lot of 3rd party libraries that way.  Also, by doing it that way - in order to scale out, you need to set up SQL Express on other machines and setup routing. The routing thing looked very complicated to setup.  SSBEA seemed much easier, and even that was quite the pain in the butt!

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up with...as the most consistent method I could find.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

#if DEBUG
            int index = Array.FindIndex(args, x => x.Equals("LAUNCHDEBUGGER", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (index > -1)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            }
#endif
```

---

```
 <LaunchInfo>
    <ImagePath>C:\SomeFolder\SomeConsoleApp.exe</ImagePath>
    <CmdLineArgs>myCommandLineArg1 LAUNCHDEBUGGER</CmdLineArgs>
    <WorkDir>C:\SomeFolder\</WorkDir>
  </LaunchInfo>
```